# How do I trigger code when a form field is changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with an "Estimated Close Date" field.

When the field is changed I want to send an email and attach the old value.

The flow:

- change estimated close date
- select update, not submit
- send email to specified users
- body of email contains old estimated close date and new date

I haven't tried much. How do I trigger this event?

Edit code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
Me.TextBox6.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
Me.TextBox1.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
Me.ComboBox2.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
Me.TextBox9.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
Me.TextBox7.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 5)
Me.TextBox8.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 6)
Me.TextBox11.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 19)
Me.TextBox12.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 20)
Me.TextBox13.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 21)
Me.TextBox14.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 18)
Me.major.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 69)
Me.loanPurpose.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 68)
Me.Collateral.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 110)
Me.PropType.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 111)
Me.Address.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 112)
Me.Underwriter.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 70)
Me.NewMoneyAmount.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 71)
End If

End Sub
```

"END Of EDIT CODE"

```
sql_query = "SELECT  [AutoID],[PotCustFormUser] ,[BorrowerName],[LoanOfficer],[ApplicationCompleteDate] ,[LoanNumber],[Comments] ,[ApplicationEnteredinPipelineDate]  ,[AdverseUser],[Denied] ,[Withdrawn] ,[CounterOffer] ,[Incomplete],[AdverseDate],[AdverseComments],[InitAssessmentUser],[InitAssessment],[InitAssessmentDate],[CommercialRM] ,[LoanAmount],[InterestRate],[EstClosedDate] ,[InitialFileReviewUWUser],[InitialFileReviewUW],[InitialFileReviewUWComments],[InitialFileReviewUWDate]  " & _
",[NeedInfoFromRMUser],[NeedInfoFromRM],[NeedInfoFromRMDate],[ConceptMemoUser],[ConceptMemoPckg],[ConceptMemoComments],[ConceptMemoDate],[ApproveConceptMemoUser],[ApproveConceptMemoPckg],[ApproveConceptMemoDate],[TermSheetUser],[TermSheet],[TermSheetComments],[TermSheetDate],[CustReviewTermSheetUser],[CustReviewTermSheet],[CustReviewTermSheetDate],[PrepareCCRUser],[PrepareCCR],[PrepareCCRComments],[PrepareCCRDate],[ReviewCCRUser],[ReviewCCR],[ReviewCCRDate],[CreditApprovalUser]" & _
",[CreditApproval] ,[CreditApprovalNA],[CreditApprovalDate],[SubmittoDocsUser],[SubmittoDocs],[DocsPersonName],[SubmittoDocsDate],[DocsCompleteUser],[DocsComplete] ,[DocsCompleteDate],[LDFMgrScreenUser],[FundingUser],[Funding],[FundingDate],[BookingCompUser],[BookingComp] ,[BookingCompDate],[LoanType],[LoanPurpose],[Underwriter],[NewMoneyAmount],[DateDocReqReceived],[OnHoldReleaseDate],[CompleteSubmissionYN],[SubmissionIssue1],[SubmissionIssue2],[DateAllSubmissionIssuesResolved],[OnHoldCB],[OnHoldDate],[DateDSAssigned],[DocSpecialist],[DocIssue1],[DocIssue2] " & _
",[DocIssue3],[DocIssue4],[DocIssue5],[Morethan5Issues],[DateallIssuesResolved],[NoFollowupsBeforeDocsComp],[DateDocsGenerated],[DateSubmittedtoQC],[DateQCComplete],[QCReworkNeeded],[DateDocsSentRMApproval],[DateRMApprovalReceived],[DateDocsFinalized],[DateDocstoClosingAgent],[DateDocsSignedbyCust],[FundingIssue1],[FundingIssue2],[DateFundedEnteredbyUser],[Phase1QCComp],[Phase1QCInitials],[Phase2QCComp],[Phase2QCInitials],[NeedInfoFromRMComments],[UWConfInfoRecUser],[UWConfInfoRec],[UWConfInfoRecUserDate],[Collateral],[PropertyType],[CollateralPropertyAddress]" & _
"FROM [C&IPipeline] where [AdverseDate] is null AND [BookingComp]=0"

rst.Open sql_query, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

sh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
    sh.Cells(1, i).value = rst.Fields(i - 1).name
Next i

rst.Close
cnn.Close


Dim lr As Long
lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

If lr = 1 Then lr = 2

With Me.ListBox1
  .ColumnCount = 8
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "0,0,100,100,80,100,100"
    .RowSource = "Support!A2:DI" & lr

End With



End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
If Me.TextBox1.value = "" Or Me.ComboBox2.value = "" Then
 MsgBox "Borrower and Loanofficer fields are required"
        Exit Sub
     Else
sql_query = "UPDATE [dbo].[C&IPipeline] " & _
    " SET [BorrowerName] = '" & Me.TextBox1.value & "'," & _
    "  [PotCustFormUser] ='" & Me.TextBox10.value & "  ', " & _
    " [Underwriter]  = '" & Me.Underwriter.value & "'," & _
    " [NewMoneyAmount]  = '" & Me.NewMoneyAmount.value & "'," & _
    "  [LoanOfficer] ='" & Me.ComboBox2.value & "  ', " & _
    " [LoanNumber] = '" & Me.TextBox7.value & "', " & _
    " [Comments] = '" & Me.TextBox8.value & " ', " & _
    " [LoanAmount] = '" & Me.TextBox11.value & " ', " & _
    " [InterestRate] = '" & Me.TextBox12.value & " ', " & _
    " [EstClosedDate] = '" & Me.TextBox13.value & " ', " & _
    " [CommercialRM] = '" & Me.TextBox14.value & " ', " & _
     " [LoanPurpose] = '" & Me.loanPurpose.value & " ', " & _
      " [Collateral] = '" & Me.Collateral.value & " ', " & _
       " [PropertyType] = '" & Me.PropType.value & " ', " & _
        " [CollateralPropertyAddress] = '" & Me.Address.value & " ', " & _
    " [LoanType] = '" & Me.major.value & " ', " & _
    " [ApplicationCompleteDate] = '" & Me.TextBox9.value & " ' " & _
 " WHERE AutoID=  " & Me.TextBox6.value

Call Execute_SQL_query(sql_query)
Call clear_Text
End If

Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)

outlookmailitem.To = ""
        outlookmailitem.cc = ""
        outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
        outlookmailitem.Subject = "New Loan in the Pipeline" & " - " & Me.TextBox1.value & " " & Me.TextBox7.value
        outlookmailitem.Body = "New loan is entered in the pipeline:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Borrower Name: " & Me.TextBox1.value & vbCrLf & "Loan Officer: " & Me.ComboBox2.value & vbCrLf & "Loan Type: " & Me.major.value & vbCrLf & _
         "Loan Number: " & Me.TextBox7.value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please assign an Underwriter and Closer."
         outlookmailitem.display
        Set outlookapp = Nothing
        Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
     
     
     
sql_query = " INSERT INTO [dbo].[C&IPipeline] ([PotCustFormUser],[BorrowerName] ,[LoanOfficer]  ,[ApplicationCompleteDate] ,[LoanNumber] ,[Comments],[Denied],[Withdrawn],[Incomplete],[Counteroffer],[InitAssessment],[InitialFileReviewUW],[NeedInfoFromRM],[ConceptMemoPckg],[ApproveConceptMemoPckg],[TermSheet],[CustReviewTermSheet],[PrepareCCR],[ReviewCCR],[CreditApproval],[SubmittoDocs],[Funding],[BookingComp],[CreditApprovalNA],DocsComplete,[LoanAmount],[InterestRate],[EstClosedDate],[CommercialRM],[LoanType],[LoanPurpose],[UWConfInfoRec],[Collateral],[PropertyType],[CollateralPropertyAddress],[Underwriter],[NewMoneyAmount])" & _
            " Values ('" & Me.TextBox10.value & "' ,'" & Me.TextBox1.value & "' ,'" & Me.ComboBox2.value & "' ,'" & Me.TextBox9.value & "','" & Me.TextBox7.value & "','" & Me.TextBox8.value & "',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'" & Me.TextBox11.value & "','" & Me.TextBox12.value & "','" & Me.TextBox13.value & "','" & Me.TextBox14.value & "','" & Me.loanPurpose.value & "','" & Me.major.value & "',0,'" & Me.Collateral.value & "','" & Me.PropType.value & "','" & Me.Address.value & "','" & Me.Underwriter.value & "','" & Me.NewMoneyAmount.value & "')"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add your code *as text* - pictures of code are discouraged here, and your question may be closed.

Comment: Presumably the current (pre-update) date is stored in the database for that record, so you can query it out before running the update...  Or save the date in a form-level variable when you load the record for editing.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you show this in the code I have attached. I will put it in text now.

Comment: Why not try it out first?

Comment: @TimWilliams don't have an idea where to start with what you are saying.

Comment: Please add the code where the record is populated on the form for editing.  You already have code which pulls the current values from the database.  You can remove the screenshots - they don't really add anything for this question.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added more code for you to look at though.

Comment: If the user is *editing* a record (which was loaded from the database) what is the code that queries the record to be edited?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have attached the code for that under "edit code:"

Answer (score 0):

When you load the record for editing you do this to populate the estimated close date from the listbox value:

```
Me.TextBox13.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 21)
```

You can declare a global variable in the form module:

```
Dim estCloseDt
```

and then populate that when you load the record for editing:

```
Me.TextBox13.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 21)
estCloseDt = Me.TextBox13.value
```

When the user clicks "update", compare `estCloseDt` with the value of `TextBox13` and if they are different then send a mail.

Comment: Where would I put the Dim estCloseDt variable? Would it be at the top of the code? or somewhere else?

Comment: At the top of the module, outside of any Sub/Function

Comment: Okay great, that is what I did. Then would I place the estCloseDt = Me.TextBox13.value right under Me.TextBox13.value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 21)?

Comment: Also, do I need to declare my email variables again in the update SUB as well or no?

Comment: Why do you have both an Update and an Insert query in the same method?  Though it looks like the Insert never gets run?

Comment: I don't they are seperate.

Comment: I have a private sub for insert and then update.

Comment: I am trying to create the part where When the user clicks "update", compare estCloseDt with the value of TextBox13 and if they are different then send a mail.

Comment: `If estCloseDt <> Me.TextBox13.value Then` ...send the mail